# Recreating the brush tool using AS3 code to develop a paint application (Bitmap class is used)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am developing a Paint Application is AS3. What I am trying is to basically mimick the MS Paint. I need to create the brush tool. The brush tool has lot of shapes in it (tip of the brush) like sqaure,circle,rhombus . I had initially planned of using the graphics class but some wise guys here advised me to use the Bitmap class. I have developed the class and it seems to work fine. But two issues that are affecting me now

1. If I increase the speed of the mouse the the drawing becomes discontinuous.
2. An idea I have for overcoming this is to calculate the points between last point and current point and draw circles in those points.But this idea is going to give me problems when I move the mouse in the pattern of a curve.

package {

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

[SWF(width=600,height=400,backgroundColor=0x000000)]

/**
* Demonstrates BitmapData's draw() command by duplicating the entirety of the stage using draw()
* whenever the space bar is pressed. A smaller copy is also drawn onto the stage to show how draw()
* can be used to transform the pixels in the image being drawn.
*/
public class DrawTest extends Sprite {

    private var _circle:Sprite;
    private var _bitmapData:BitmapData;


    /**
    * Constructor. Creates bitmap that will be drawn into and circle that will follow the mouse.
    * A listener is also set up to handle then a key is pressed.
    */
    public function DrawTest() {

        createBitmap();
        createCircle();

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,_handleMouseEventBrush);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,_handleMouseEventBrush);

    }

    /**
    * Creates bitmap data that the stage contents will be drawn into and adds this to the stage.
    */
    private function createBitmap():void {
        _bitmapData=new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight,true,0x000000);
        var bitmap:Bitmap=new Bitmap(_bitmapData);
        addChild(bitmap);
    }

    /**
    * Creates a circle shape that is set to follow the mouse as it moves.
    */
    private function createCircle():void {
        _circle=new Sprite  ;
        _circle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        _circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,10);
        _circle.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(_circle);
        _circle.x=stage.mouseX;
        _circle.y=stage.mouseY;
        _circle.startDrag();

    }


    private function _handleMouseEventBrush(e:MouseEvent):void {



        switch (String(e.type)) {

            case "mouseDown" :
                _bitmapData.draw(stage);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,_handleMouseEventBrush);
                break;

            case "mouseUp" :
                stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,_handleMouseEventBrush);
                break;

            case "mouseMove" :
                _bitmapData.draw(stage);


        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone idea as to how to overcome this.

Comment: Just a few tips to make things faster. You don't need to add the circle to any parent before drawing it (`_bitmapData.draw(_circle)`). You may use `Shape` instead of `Sprite` since you only need to draw in it.

Comment: _bitmapData.draw(stage) is very slow. I have answered another question about optimisation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996984/is-it-possible-to-improve-the-performance-of-this-drawing-technique/3997079#3997079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to use the Event.ENTER_FRAME to execute the draw commands. MOUSE_MOVE is executed more often and the screen is re-rendered by flash depending on the framerate. But I am not sure if this is better.
greets

Comment: I tried using the enterframe as per your suggestion. It does not help to the extent needed. Sure, when the frame rate is more the smoothness increases or decreases as per the increase or decrease of the frame rate. But it is not possible to set a very high frame rate just for this purpose. Even if it is high the still there are gaps when the mouse is moved fast. Anyway thanks a lot for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like Grafitti - http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/

It is very simple to use and has a lot of interesting features.

Tip: use the 2.5 version